# Render only certain levels of UI - Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

Using UGUI, I have a Canvas with frew UI GameObjects inside.

Is there any way to get a render of the lower UI elements of a certain UI element?

I want to try to code a blur system that allows stacking UI elements.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `Layers`, which are traditionally used for sorting objects to Render in unity: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html

You should be able to assign the different objects to layers to control them.